# GRUB error: syntax error. error: Incorrect command

Tags: ubuntu, grub2

When I boot my laptop, which has Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS os, I meet the following problem in grub.

```bsh
error: syntax error. 
error: Incorrect command.
error: syntax error. 
error: syntax error. 
error: Incorrect command.
error: syntax error. 
error: syntax error. 
error: Incorrect command.
error: syntax error. 
error: can't find command `recordfail'.
error: can't find command `load_video'.

Press any key to continue..._
```

After waiting a moment or pressing any key, it could boot. And anything else is not wrong.

Comment: Try running boot-repair: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104855/how-to-make-grub-menu-appear-instead-grub-minimal-bash-like-in-booting/1105737#1105737

Comment: Cool! It works, thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. For the sake of future readers I've reposted the answer on this site. You can accept it by clicking the grey check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After booting the hard way, open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and install [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Then type `boot-repair` and a menu will appear:

[image: boot-repair menu.png]

Select the recommended option.

If your system boots normally after recommended repair great. If not post the link to the problems reported.

---

#### Caveats

On some systems this annoyance can occur:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/938633/boot-repair-created-too-many-grub-menu-entries-for-windows/1022700#1022700

If this happens to you, visit the link for a solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works well. :)