# Syntax error in grub.cfg on update-grub

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, grub

I run Ubuntu 20.04 and have this error when I do an `update-grub` command:

```
root@ubuntu:/# update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Création du fichier de configuration GRUB…
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-25-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-25-generic
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-53-generic
CentOS Linux 8 (Core) trouvé sur /dev/sdb9
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-25-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-25-generic
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-53-generic
CentOS Linux 8 (Core) trouvé sur /dev/sdb9
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-25-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-25-generic
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-53-generic
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-25-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-25-generic
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-53-generic
CentOS Linux 8 (Core) trouvé sur /dev/sdb9
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-25-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-25-generic
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-53-generic
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
erreur : syntax error.
erreur : Incorrect command.
erreur : syntax error.
erreur : Incorrect command.
erreur : syntax error.
Erreur de syntaxe à la ligne 159
Des erreurs de syntaxe sont détectées dans le fichier de configuration
de GRUB. Veuillez vérifier qu'il n'y a pas d'erreur dans les fichiers
/etc/default/grub et /etc/grub.d/*. Sinon veuillez signaler un bogue
en joignant le fichier /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new.
```

I checked the file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new` at line 159 as suggested, and here is the snippet corresponding to the line and its surroundings:

```
152 ### END /etc/grub.d/31_linux_xen ###
153 
154 ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/34_memtest86+ ###
155 ### END /etc/grub.d/34_memtest86+ ###
156 
157 ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/35_os-prober_proxy ###
158 submenu "Options avancées pour Ubuntu"{
159 function gfxmode {
160         set gfxpayload="${1}"
161         if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
162                 set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
163         else
164                 set vt_handoff=
165         fi
166 }
167 if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
168   if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
169     if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
170       if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
171         set linux_gfx_mode=keep
172       else
173         set linux_gfx_mode=text
174       fi
175     else
176       set linux_gfx_mode=text
177     fi
178   else
179     set linux_gfx_mode=keep
180   fi
181 else
182   set linux_gfx_mode=text
183 fi
184 export linux_gfx_mode
```

I can see that there seems to be a problem with line 158 `submenu "Options avancées pour Ubuntu"{` which never closes its "{" but I am unable to find where this comes from...

I already tried running boot-repair (as suggested on this answer [GRUB error: syntax error. error: Incorrect command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/523905/grub-error-syntax-error-error-incorrect-command))
but the first command asked to launch is:
`sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/isw_cbgbbifgbg_Volume1p2" dpkg --configure -a`
and it gives me the same problem of syntax error.

Comment: Proxy files are not grub2, but from grub customizer. If Customizer not working,  you have to do a total reinstall of grub2.  I once had a missing } and it showed error at end of file when it was really in the middle somewhere. But it was my own 40_custom that had the error. Did you change settings in /etc/default/grub? If those are not correct they can cause similar errors.

Comment: I didn't change my /etc/defaut/grub but I had grub-customizer. How can I do a total reinstall of grub ? I am from a live USB key.

Comment: From live installer, probably easiest is Boot-Repair.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ Other option is a full chroot into your system and use that to update/modify system. https://askubuntu.com/questions/53578/can-i-install-in-uefi-mode-with-the-alternate-installer/57380#57380

Comment: Thank you for your help. I figured out that the issue came from the installation of my third OS (Centos) which broke up the execution order somehow of grub-update. Some instructions in the file /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new had "^M" ending lines... anyway I didn't have time to repair in time I had to reinstall my Ubuntu and remove my Centos.

Comment: If os-prober does not correctly create a new boot entry due to some logic issue, often better to just turn it off and copy a good boot stanza from the other install into 40_custom.

Comment: Oh ok I didn't know it was possible, I will try to remember for my next crazy installations, thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `update-grub` command executes `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg "$@"`, which in turn executes the scripts in directory `/etc/grub.d/`. Those scripts create the contents of `grub.cfg`, and the comment lines like

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/35_os-prober_proxy ###
```

will indicate which script is responsible for each part of the `grub.cfg` file.

In your case, you should probably investigate the `/etc/grub.d/35_os-prober_proxy` script, and possibly the scripts immediately after it in the directory (in default ASCII alphanumberical sorting order).

On the other hand, in my Debian 10 system, the `function gfxmode {` line is part of the output of `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`, which is responsible for generating the plain Linux boot entries, then there is another script `20_linux_xen` to create boot entries for Xen-style virtualization if it's installed, and then `30_os-prober` to detect and add boot entries for other operating systems. Apparently Ubuntu does things somewhat differently, but it makes me suspect the parts of `grub.cfg` may have been produced out of order somehow.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I figured out that the issue came from the installation of my third OS (Centos, alongside my dual boot) which broke up the execution order somehow of grub-update. Some instructions in the file /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new had "^M" ending lines... anyway I didn't have time to repair in time I had to reinstall my Ubuntu and remove my Centos because I had to work on monday...

Answer (score 0):

With

- debian trixie
- grub-customizer 5.2.3

Run:

```shell
sudo cp /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new /. # put your home path here
sudo rm /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new
grub-customizer
```

Then push the revert button (right-upper position) and apply.